# Given a root α of the polynomial, compare the field extension $Q(α)$ with $Q(α^3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Consider the polynomial $F(t)= 2021t^7+6t^6+2017t^5-2t^4-t^3+2t^2-t+5$ , this is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[t]$ because it's irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2[t]$ (it has no factors of degree 1,2 or 3) , so now we consider one of its complex roots $α$ . We obviously have $\mathbb{Q}(α^3) \subset \mathbb{Q}(α)$ , but for the converse I have no idea on how to proceed. I thought of trying to find a polynomial for which $α^3$ is a root (and possibly find its minimal polynomial), but the expressions are very messy and I can't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q(\alpha^3)] \leq 3$, because $\alpha$ is a root of $X^3-\alpha^3 \in \Bbb Q(\alpha^3)[X]$. But we also have $7=[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]=[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q(\alpha^3)][\Bbb Q(\alpha^3):\Bbb Q]$, so $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q(\alpha^3)]$ divides $7$ and is less than or equal to $3$. Thus $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q(\alpha^3)]=1$.

Comment: Basically, we can use this to prove the same statement for all the powers of $α$ up to 6, just by tweaking the polynomial, since 7 is prime , is it correct?

Comment: @SamueleMonitto yes.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

The degree $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^3) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is at most $3$ and divides $7$.